# How can I modify, compile and install tun.ko?

Tags: linux-kernel, debian, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, tun

I've never compiled a single kernel module. I would like to understand how to change the source of a kernel module, compile and install it on Debian SO.

Can someone illustrate the steps or tell me a tutorial about it?

Thank you and everyone.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit confusing since a .ko file represents a kernel object. In other words, it has already been compiled.

To edit the module you would need the source code, most likely tun.c and some related files.

StackOverflow is more meant for specific questions to be answered, not a tutorial site. Please do some research about Linux modules and make an attempt to install the module yourself. Some good sites for beginners:

- kernel.org
- https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/linux-device-drivers/0596005903/
- http://derekmolloy.ie/writing-a-linux-kernel-module-part-1-introduction/

The last of these is the least comprehensive, but quickest to get you up and running. Once you get to the point where you have detailed questions, post them here and you will get better help.

Comment: I'm following the steps from [Maros Michalik](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168279/how-do-i-build-a-single-in-tree-kernel-module). But I have to run  `make SUBDIRS=scripts/mod` for every change of the .c module? Now it's compiling everything and it takes some time obviously. I would like to work with the single module.

Comment: You can work with the module on its own. Just create a Makefile to compile the .c file into a .ko file. Some info on Makefiles here: http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x181.html